# How to insert values from a column from other one, getting column name through a query

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know how to insert values from a column  with a dynamic name. I am getting the column name like this:

```
select  
    (select a.COLUMN_NAME 
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a 
     where a.COLUMN_NAME = 'COMMENTS') TEST 
from jan_dic d
```

I have a `master_table` with a column with a all unique column names and the other column has all approved names for the first column as shown below.

```
column1  | column2
---------+------------
capital  | cap_amount
capital  | amount_cap
capital  | cap_amt
```

My question is how can I insert values in another table with a column name = 'capital' from other tables if I get column name approved.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I get that English isn't your first language but this doesn't make much sense. What do you mean by approving columns? And what are really trying to do here? You need to post the table definitions, some sample data and the desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: look for `dynamic query`

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @colname sysname = (
select  
    (select a.COLUMN_NAME 
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a 
     where a.COLUMN_NAME = 'COMMENTS') TEST 
from jan_dic d
)

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
   INSERT INTO othertable (' + @colname + N') VALUES ...
'

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
```